# Testing of your faith produces endurance

Tags: james

In James 1:3 (NASB)

> knowing that the testing of your faith produces endurance.

Does that mean it's the testing itself that produces endurance or the successful passing of the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask an Olympic athlete - the endurance produced for whatever skill is made in the trials of practice, including failures.  Note the helpful proverb -

> Prov 24:16 - For though a righteous man may fall seven times, he still
> gets up; but the wicked stumble in bad times.

Success is not dependent on how many times one fails, but on trusting the Lord and how many times one gets up again.  In 2 Peter 1 we find that this perseverance is part of the so-called staircase of the Christian:

> **5** For this very reason, make every effort to add to your faith virtue; and to virtue, knowledge; **6** and to knowledge,
> self-control; and to self-control, **perseverance**; and to perseverance,
> godliness; **7** and to godliness, brotherly kindness; and to
> brotherly kindness, love. **8** For if you possess these qualities and
> continue to grow in them, they will keep you from being ineffective
> and unproductive in your knowledge of our Lord Jesus Christ.

Comment: Amen!!!!!!!!!!!